# Find the cardinality of $S=\{(x,y,z) \in \Bbb R^3: x^2+y^2=4\}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

Find the cardinality of $S=\{(x,y,z) \in \Bbb R^3: x^2+y^2=4\}$.

I know that as $S\subseteq \Bbb R^3 \implies |S|\leq  \mathfrak{c}$.

My conjecture is that $|S|= \mathfrak c$, I think this is true because the set describes a cylinder in $\Bbb R^3$, and if you (bear with me) unfold this cylinder, you get some kind of rectangle ($\subset$ of some plane) which seems to be equinumerous to a closed rectangle of $\Bbb R^2$.

I'm not sure I made my idea clear.  Is there any way to prove this?

Comment: A bijection from the cylinder to a subset of the plane ought to work. It may not be easy to find a bijection that takes the cylinder to a closed rectangle.

Comment: For any $x \in [0,1]$ there exists a $y$ such that $(x,y,z) \in S$ (and $z$ can be arbitrary). You can deduce a surjection onto $[0,1]$ and prove the claim.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The restriction of the identity map in $\Bbb{R}^3$ to $S$ shows gives an injection $S\to\Bbb{R}^3$ so $|S|\le |\Bbb{R}^3|=|\Bbb{R}|$

Then you can create a surjection $S\to \Bbb{R}$ defined by $(x,y,z)\mapsto z$, which shows that $|S|\ge \Bbb{R}$.

Thus $|S|=|\Bbb{R}|$